# How to draw DFA of language A={w | Every even position of w has symbol 0}?

Tags: computation-theory, dfa, nfa, automata-theory

I need to draw a DFA for a machine. Machine accepts the language A.

Language A={w | Every even position of w has symbol 0} and
Σ = {0,1}.

I drawed the DFA.Not sure if it is correct.

Here is my DFA,
[DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb9wQ.jpg) [picture]

I want to know if it is correct or not.If it is wrong then how to correct it.

Comment: it is not correct.. please try again

Comment: whats wrong then?

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, we need to know which symbol we're about to get - an even-position symbol or an odd-position symbol - and if we're about to get an even-position symbol, only accept a zero. We can recognize whether we're about to get an even-position or odd-position symbol with two states: qOdd and qEven. We also need a way for the DFA to recognize it has seen a violation of the constraint that prevents it from accepting the string later; we can call that state qDead. Each state needs two transitions; dead states always transition to themselves, and qOdd/qEven will transition to each other until the condition gets violated by seeing a 1 in qEven.

Our DFA looks like this:

```
        /-----0----\          /-0,1-\
        |          |          |     |
        V          |          |     |
----->qOdd-0,1->qEven--1-->qDead<---/
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be correct DFA in the below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The language accepted by this dfa will be l={ε,1,10,101,1010,......}
So in this dfa as soon as my string starts with 0 i go to a dead state, state q0 represents odd position and q2 state represents even position at q2 state if i get 1 i go to a dead state because we cannot have 1 at even position.

[minimum dfa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnYtw.jpg)